# How to get revalidated data from the server side page (update user login state)

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

how to get revalidated from the server side page as i am using here next auth session to render the diff page depending up user login status

```
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import React from "react";
import { authOptions } from "./api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
export default async function page() {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container mx-auto px-4 mt-6">
                {session ? (
                    <h1>Protected Content</h1>
                ) : (
                    <p>Login karle mere bhai</p>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

but when i make login a redirect to the home page the state of the user doesn't get changed